# Responsive Scroll on top Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to create a scroll on top button. Its working as intended. However, when i resize the browser screen its keep shifting its place. Following is my CSS code:

```
#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 27px; 
    z-index: 99; 
    border: none; 
    outline: none; 
    background-color: $primary-color;
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
}
```

Here is the Javascript code which i am using for the functionality of the button:

```
// When user scrolls down 920px from the top of the document, show the button
    window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 920 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 920) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
    }
```

[image: Problem area screen shot]

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle that recreates the problem please, everything looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to change the css of the button based on the screen size.

You can learn more about it from here.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, you should not have a problem at all. The position is fixed. Regardless the browser resize, #myBtn will remain where it is.

```js
// When user scrolls down 920px from the top of the document, show the button
  
  window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 920 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 920) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
    }
```

```css
#myBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 27px; 
    z-index: 99; 
    border: none; 
    outline: none; 
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="myBtn"></div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div><div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
<div>Some Text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately everything is fine in between the large and small screen sizes however the problem is with medium screen sizes. I have attached the screen shot if the problem area in the original question above. I have also verified if there is any specificity issue. But there are non.

Comment: The location is still fixed, bottom 100px. It only appears more significant because of the screen size. Are you interested in updating the bottom value based on the browser size?

Comment: I found the solution i guess. The button is a child of another div which changes its bottom padding when we resize the browser. Now i am trying to include the html code using javascript. So that is will automatically include the code when the page loads.

Comment: Good. In the snippet, you will see that the button is attached to body. Interestingly, since you are using fixed, it should not make so much difference.

Comment: Yes, solved the problem using JavaScript. Thanks to everyone for their participation.